# Can a spiral be represented implicitly as $F(x)+G(y)+H(x+y) = 0$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, curves, plane-curves

> Can a spiral be represented implicitly as $F(x)+G(y)+H(x+y) = 0$, where $F,G,H$ are continuous differentiable real-valued functions?

**Definition:** A *spiral* is a simple curve $C\subset \mathbb R^2$ with parametric representation
$$
  C_i = \Big\{
  \Big(
    r(t) \sin\big(\phi(t)\big), 
    r(t) \cos\big(\phi(t)\big)
  \Big), 
  t\in \mathbb R_+
\Big\},
$$
where both $r$ and $\phi$ are continuous functions such that $r(0)=0$, and both $\phi(t)$ and $r(t)$ go to infinity as $t\to\infty$.

The implicit form $F(x)+G(y)=0$ is very restrictive, in the post [Can a spiral be represented as $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612285/can-a-spiral-be-represented-as-fxgy-0/4612293#4612293) it was argued that no spiral can be represented that way and more general case is discussed here: [Can an $n$-armed spiral be represented as $F(x)+G(y)=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612826/can-an-n-armed-spiral-be-represented-as-fxgy-0). The form is also very restrictive on closed curves that can be represented that way: [Closed curves of the form $F(x)+G(y)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607123/closed-curves-of-the-form-fxgy-0/4612265#4612265).

I'm interested whether adding "one degree of freedom" in the implicit formula by including the term $H(x+y)$ in it will allow for different types of curves to be representable that way.

Comment: Shouldn't both $r$ and $\phi$ be *increasing* and continuous? [Usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral#Two-dimensional), $\phi$ is just the identity.

Comment: A simpler question would be: Can every spiral be represented by an implicit equation $F(x, y) = 0$. For the logarithmic a solution is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3139868/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for sharing. It is not explicitly said in the post you cite, but all the answers assume there that the goal is to find $f(x,y)$ composed of elementary functions. In contrast here the functions $F,G,H$ can be any continuous differentiable functions, even if there was no known way to construct them (and their existence was based on the axiom of choice). From the perspective of this question, any spiral $C$ (whose graph is a closed set) can be implicit described by $f(x,y)=\mathop{dist}((x,y),C)^2$. (I square the distance to make the function smooth.)

Comment: @MartinR I agree that $r$ and $\phi$ being increasing is more standard. I did not require it in order to allow simple examples in which the spiral would be piecewise continuous. On the other hand this much freedom allows for some really weird spirals (forming a maze for example), but I suppose that it is fine.